# Starting server side operation from GUI and updating GUI once operation is done

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, soap

I have a WCF service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
void BeginDelete(MyParams params);
```

, which looks like:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource;
...
public void BeginDelete(MyParams params)
{
    ....
    _cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancelToken = _cancelSource.Token;
    var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            bool done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                // Deleting stuff from database...
                // Carry on deleting until there is no more to delete
                // or user cancels midway.
            }

            // Operation is now complete so update GUI (e.g. callback).
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }, cancelToken);

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Faulted...");
    }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled...");
    }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
}
```

I am calling into this service uing SOAP from my web GUI (e.g. a jQuery dialog with a button 'Delete').

While the operation is in progress, I show a dialog with a progress bar but here is my problem...

The dialog remains open because it does not know that the operation is finished.

How can I communicate a request to update the GUI from the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this after your other `ContinueWith`s:

```
task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        dialog.Close()
    });
```